# OS X [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval...] function in windowDidLoad not working

Tags: macos, cocoa, splash-screen, nswindowcontroller

I am a iOS developer and going to develop an OS X application.
However they are so different from each other.

I want to add a splash screen at the application startup.

```
- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

 // Hide main window
 [self.window orderOut:nil];

 SplashWindowController *splashWindowController = [[SplashWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"SplashWindowController"];

 [NSApp runModalForWindow:splashWindowController.window];
 [splashWindowController release];

 // Show main window
 ...
```

And here is "SplashWindowController.m"

```
- (void)windowDidLoad {
  [super windowDidLoad];

  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(hideSplash) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

- (void)hideSplash {
  [NSApp endSheet:self.window];
  [self.window orderOut:nil];
}
```

I can see the appeared splash, but hideSplash function is never called.
What's the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm wondering that you don't get an error, but this line has a typo:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target self selector:@selector(hideSplash) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

it should be

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(hideSplash) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

On the other hand, you could try this one:

```
NSTimer *theTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(hideSplash) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:theTimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

I'm not sure if the [NSTimer…] is destroyed too soon… Assigning it to an instance should be fine. Also afaik the run loop is interrupted so you could try adding the timer to the main run loop.

Comment: Sorry, I typed wrongly. It's not correct answer. I just modified the question.

Comment: I already tried to add the NSTimer member variable in the SplashWindowController and retain... But the result is same.

Comment: …did you try adding it tho the `mainRunLoop`? ;-)

Comment: scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:invocation:repeats: and scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats: create timers that get automatically added to an NSRunLoop, meaning that you don't have to add them yourself. Having them added to an NSRunLoop is what causes them to fire.

With timerWithTimeInterval:invocation:repeats: and timerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:, you have to add the timer to a run loop manually